# This code doesnt show the final result when executed

Tags: c, debugging

This C code compiles successful, however when I execute, it asks for the number, but in the end it doesnt show the final result, instead it shows an empty line:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{ 
    int number, u, t, h, sum;
    char parity[7] = "";
    float result;

    printf("Number : ");
    scanf("%u", &number);

    u = (int)number % 10;
    t = (int)number % 100 / 10;
    h = (int)number / 100;
    sum =  u + t + h;

    if (number >= 100 && number <= 999)
    {
        if (number % 2 == 0)
        {
            strcpy(parity[7], "even");
            result = pow(sum, 2);
            printf("%u + %u + %u = %u : %s ---> %u*%u = %.0f \n", u, t, h, sum, parity[7], sum, sum, result);
        }
        else if (number % 2 == 1)
        {
            strcpy(parity[7], "odd");
            result = sqrt(sum);
            printf("%u + %u + %u = %u : %s ---> Sqrt(%u) = %.2f \n", u, t, h, sum, parity[7], sum, result);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The argument `parity[7]` is out of bounds. I suggest just `parity` for `%s` format spec. Check out compiler warnings!

Comment: `u = (int)number % 10;` Those casts are useless. `number` already is an `int`.

Comment: `strcpy(parity[7], "even");` should produce a compiler warning. Don't ignore compiler warnings. https://godbolt.org/z/1xs4dn7ze

Comment: Aside: a square is best obtained with `(float)sum * sum`;

Comment: `%u` is for `unsigned int`. You don't have any `unsigned` variables, so all of the `%u` in the `scanf` and the `printf`s should be changed to `%d`.

Comment: "The code compiles successful". This short code generated **10 warnings**. Please enable them.

Comment: You seem to have misunderstood how arrays are defined: `<underlying type; here char><name of the array, here parity>[<length of the array, here 7>];` – and later on you address the array as a whole only by its name – brackets after mean indexing it, i.e. accessing the array at a specific position.

Comment: Side note (general): As you want a `float` result anyway there's no need to calculate `double`s first – so I'd rather prefer the `...f` variants of (`powf`, `sqrtf`).

Comment: or work with `double`. Never work with `float` unless there is a very good reason why you can't work with `double`.

Comment: no, it does not compile successfully, see my answer for details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the results of your posted code.

This cannot be considered a successful compile. regardless of what the compiler says

```
gcc -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11 -c "untitled.c" -o "untitled.o" 
untitled.c: In function ‘main’:
untitled.c:11:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘printf’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   11 |     printf("Number : ");
      |     ^~~~~~
untitled.c:11:5: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘printf’
untitled.c:4:1: note: include ‘<stdio.h>’ or provide a declaration of ‘printf’
    3 | #include <math.h>
  +++ |+#include <stdio.h>
    4 |
untitled.c:12:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘scanf’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   12 |     scanf("%u", &number);
      |     ^~~~~
untitled.c:12:5: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘scanf’
untitled.c:12:5: note: include ‘<stdio.h>’ or provide a declaration of ‘scanf’
untitled.c:12:13: warning: format ‘%u’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat=]
   12 |     scanf("%u", &number);
      |            ~^   ~~~~~~~
      |             |   |
      |             |   int *
      |             unsigned int *
      |            %u
untitled.c:23:26: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘strcpy’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   23 |             strcpy(parity[7], "even");
      |                    ~~~~~~^~~
      |                          |
      |                          char
In file included from untitled.c:2:
/usr/include/string.h:122:14: note: expected ‘char * restrict’ but argument is of type ‘char’
  122 | extern char *strcpy (char *__restrict __dest, const char *__restrict __src)
      |              ^~~~~~
untitled.c:24:22: warning: conversion from ‘double’ to ‘float’ may change value [-Wfloat-conversion]
   24 |             result = pow(sum, 2);
      |                      ^~~
untitled.c:25:42: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 6 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
   25 |             printf("%u + %u + %u = %u : %s ---> %u*%u = %.0f \n", u, t, h, sum, parity[7], sum, sum, result);
      |                                         ~^                                      ~~~~~~~~~
      |                                          |                                            |
      |                                          char *                                       int
      |                                         %d
untitled.c:29:26: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘strcpy’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   29 |             strcpy(parity[7], "odd");
      |                    ~~~~~~^~~
      |                          |
      |                          char
In file included from untitled.c:2:
/usr/include/string.h:122:14: note: expected ‘char * restrict’ but argument is of type ‘char’
  122 | extern char *strcpy (char *__restrict __dest, const char *__restrict __src)
      |              ^~~~~~
untitled.c:30:22: warning: conversion from ‘double’ to ‘float’ may change value [-Wfloat-conversion]
   30 |             result = sqrt(sum);
      |                      ^~~~
untitled.c:31:42: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 6 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
   31 |             printf("%u + %u + %u = %u : %s ---> Sqrt(%u) = %.2f \n", u, t, h, sum, parity[7], sum, result);
      |                                         ~^                                         ~~~~~~~~~
      |                                          |                                               |
      |                                          char *                                          int
      |                                         %d
Compilation finished successfully.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{ 
    int number, u, t, h, sum;
    char parity[7];
    float result;

    printf("Number : ");
    scanf("%u", &number);

    u = (int)number % 10;
    t = (int)number % 100 / 10;
    h = (int)number / 100;
    sum =  u + t + h;

    if (number >= 100 && number <= 999)
    {
        if (number % 2 == 0)
        {
            strcpy(parity, "even");
            result = pow(sum, 2);
            printf("%d + %d + %d = %d : %s ---> %u*%u = %.0f \n", u, t, h, sum, parity, sum, sum, result);
        }
        else if (number % 2 == 1)
        {
            strcpy(parity, "odd");
            result = sqrt(sum);
            printf("%d + %d + %d = %d : %s ---> Sqrt(%u) = %.2f \n", u, t, h, sum, parity, sum, result);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Adding an explanation of what was wrong with the original code alongside the corrected version would be more helpful to understand the underlying problem issue.